# Not all ListView Items are stretched when using multiple ItemTemplates

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, windows-phone-8.1

I'm working on a Windows Phone 8.1 app and I need to show two different item templates depending on the state of an item.

To switch between my templates I'm using `TemplateSelector` abstract class suggested on some blog or something. Here's the code:

```
public abstract class TemplateSelector : ContentControl
{
    public abstract DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container);

    protected override void OnContentChanged(object oldContent, object newContent)
    {
        base.OnContentChanged(oldContent, newContent);

        ContentTemplate = SelectTemplate(newContent, (DependencyObject)this);
    }
}
```

After that I created an inherited class:

```
public class LibraryItemTemplateSelector : TemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate Expanded
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public DataTemplate Collapsed
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        var v = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values;
        var ffs = item as FFStory;
        if (ffs != null)
        {
            if (v.ContainsKey("alwaysExpanded"))
            {
                if ((bool)v["alwaysExpanded"] == true)
                    return Expanded;
            }
            var result = ...
            ...
            if (result == 1)
                return Collapsed;
            else return Expanded;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Next, I used the class name inside the `<ItemTemplate><DataTewmplate>` tags in XAML like so to assign templates to items:

```
<local:LibraryItemTemplateSelector Content="{Binding}" Expanded="{StaticResource expandedItem}" Collapsed="{StaticResource collapsedItem}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
```

***Problem:***

When I start the app, the width of all items seems random.

The expanded items are all full-width, but that's understandable. The description textblock which has `WrapText=WrapWholeWords` set just stretches the box out.

Collapsed items, hovewer, don't seem to work according to any rules. Many items have width the same as the title `TextBlock`, but some are ~30px longer. Sometimes there's properly working full-width item, but that seems to be random.

I've also tried using these templates separately, without `LibraryItemTemplateSelector` class and that works just fine.

***Conslusions:***

I think there's something wrong with the `TemplateSelector` abstract class because without it everything works fine but I can't tell what's wrong exactly.

I've set the `HorizontalContentAlignment` to Stretch in `ItemContainerStyle`, I've also added `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"` attribute wherever possible in desperation. Needless to say, that didn't work.

What am I doing wrong here? Is there something wrong with the abstract class above or maybe ItemTemplate just isn't supposed to work this way?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for `DataTemplateSelector`:

```
    public class ProfilePageTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
    {
        public DataTemplate dtPostTemplate { get; set; }
        public DataTemplate dtCommentTemplate { get; set; }

        protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore( object item, DependencyObject container )
        {
            var uiElement = container as UIElement;
            if ( uiElement == null )
            {
                return base.SelectTemplate( item, container );
            }

            if ( item is Post )
            {
                return dtPostTemplate;
            }
            else if ( item is Comment )
            {
                return dtCommentTemplate;
            }
            return base.SelectTemplateCore( item, container );
        }
```